# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, 2013, sharepoint-online, authentication

I am developing a C# console application on my local computer running on Windows 8. My target SharePoint server is SharePoint Online on Office 365. I am trying to get the web site name using web.Title property of CSOM of SharePoint 2013. I wrote the following code inside the main function to do that.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new    ClientContext("https://innergen.sharepoint.com/sites/mydevsite");
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.WriteLine("Web Site Name : " + web.Title);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Now when I run my project in debug mode, I receive an error saying "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden". I used the same Microsoft Account to log in to both my SharePoint Online account and Windows 8 OS(local machine). Can anybody tell me what's wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: I too am writing a similar application and use the SharePointOnlineCredential exactly as shown here, but my program crashes "silently". Has anybody else seen this, and more importantly solved it? I don't do much with SP, so it would be a big help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `SharePointOnlineCredentials` that handles all the handshaking, claims and oauth in SharePoint online.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://innergen.sharepoint.com/sites/mydevsite"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
 
    foreach (char c in "yourpassword".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
 
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("yourlogin@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);
 
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
 
    clientContext.Load(web);
 
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I had problems with reference because dll is version 14(SharePointOnlineCredentials not exist), and have updated my dll and work fine. thanks!

link of the download SDK:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585

Answer (score 5):

if you are trying to run  it using network credential try the below code

```
clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

Also try adding headers

```
context.ExecutingWebRequest += clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;


static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            }
            catch
            { throw; }

        }
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
            Web web = context.Web;
            context.ExecutingWebRequest += clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
            context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Comment: Is the order between `.Credentials` and `.ExecutingWebRequest +=` important? And what about when comapred to `Web web = context.web;`?